# Any data passed to a Firebase Function returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've made a firebase function which every time I pass data to it and try to use the data, it returns that the data is undefined. This is the function I made:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Cloud Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

// CORS Express middleware to enable CORS Requests.
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

admin.initializeApp();

exports.addUser = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    const handleError = (error) => {
        console.log('Error creating new user:', error);

        //sends back that we've been unable to add the user with error
        return res.status(500).json({
            error: err,
        });
    }

    try {
        return cors(req, res, async () => {
            console.log(req);
    
            const uid = req.uid;
            const dob = req.dob;
            const postcode = req.postcode;
            const sex = req.sex;
            const username = req.username;

            admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({
                dob:dob,
                postcode:postcode,
                sex:sex,
                username:username,
            })
            .then(function(userRecord) {
                console.log('Successfully created new user:', userRecord.username);

                // Send back a message that we've succesfully added a user
                return res.status(201).json({
                    message: 'User stored',
                    id: req.body.uid,
                });
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                return handleError(error);
            });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return handleError(error);
      }
  });
```

This is how I call it within react:

```
    const addUserFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addUser');

    console.log("Calling user func " + user.uid)

    addUserFunc({
      uid:user.uid,
      dob:dob,
      postcode:postcode,
      sex:sex,
      username:username,
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      setErrors(prev => ([...prev, err.message]))
    });
```

I've printed the data before sending the request and it definitely exists. I've also tried getting it within the function using req.body and req.query but this just returns the same.

This is the error I get in the firebase function logs:

```
Error: Value for argument "document path" is not a valid resource path. The path must be a non-empty string.
    at Object.validateResourcePath (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/path.js:406:15)
    at CollectionReference.doc (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1982:20)
    at cors (/srv/index.js:44:51)
    at cors (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)
    at /srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17
    at originCallback (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)
    at /srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13
    at optionsCallback (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)
    at corsMiddleware (/srv/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)
    at exports.addUser.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:31:16)
```

This is the error return in the web console for the react app:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://***/addUser' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I tested the function within using the emulator and passing the values using the link which works there but just not when deployed.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Cloud Function is defined as a [HTTPS Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), which means that you can access it over a URL, but then you're calling it from your code as a [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). The two types are different and not interchangeable.

---

If you want to use the `firebase.functions().httpsCallable('addUser');` in your client code, you'll have to modify your Cloud Function to be a Callable Function too. This mostly means that you get the parameters from `data` instead of `res`, and `return` responses instead of sending them through `res`.

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    ...
    const uid = context.auth.uid; // automatically passed to Callable Functions

    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({
        dob: data.dob,
        postcode: data.postcode,
        sex: data.sex,
        username: data.username,
    })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
        return {
            message: 'User stored',
            id: req.body.uid,
        };
    }).catch(err => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('dabase-error', error);
    })
});
```

---

Alternatively, you can leave your Cloud Function as is and instead modify the calling code to use something like `fetch()`.

Comment: Thanks very much that fixed it! I made the change to the Firebase function and data is now coming through perfectly.